# Array dentro de un Foreach | ¿Alguien que me ayude que me salga igual?

Tags: php

```php
<?php
$tech = array(109, 110, 111);
$FleetsOnPlanet = array();

foreach ($tech as $FleetID) {
    $FleetsOnPlanet[] = array($FleetID => 1);
}

echo json_encode($FleetsOnPlanet);

echo "<br>";
echo "quiero esto pero en el foreach de arriba";
echo "<br>";

$tecs = array(109 => 1, 110 => 1, 111 => 1);
echo json_encode($tecs);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cambia esta línea:

```
$FleetsOnPlanet[] = array($FleetID => 1);
```

por esta:

```
$FleetsOnPlanet[$FleetID] = 1;
```

porque del otro modo estás agregando un array dentro de un elemento del array principal, y de este otro modo estás agregando una clave y un valor al elemento del principal.

Comment: Gracias, perfecto.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP ves?  El OP ha regresado y se ha dado cuenta de mi mensaje :-)  Ya podemos borrar estos comentarios para dejar limpia la respuesta de ruido, gracias!